# What's the difference between usage of these two tense forms?

Tags: tense, difference

> I'm meeting John after class today.
>
> I will meet John after class today.

They differ in the tense form as present continuous and simple future respectively. But do they differ in usage or meaning in any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do use "present continuous " for future event while we are talking about arrangements. Most probably, One or more people is aware of the event and some preparation has already completed.

Will (future simple) is used to express future intentions
that are decided at the time of speaking (spontaneous
offers, promises and decisions).

1) I'm meeting John after class today. ( You already called John and told him about your meeting after class)

2) I will meet John after class today. (  X:  I want to meet my best friend after class. Y : Oh really, then I will meet John after class today as he is my best friend. )

Comment: Your phrase **One or more people is** seems a bit erroneous. Is it?

Comment: @Anubhav Singh I don't think so. You can use both [ One or more people is /are ]. Have a look at this article : http://onlinewritingtraining.com.au/2017/04/24/one-or-more-is-or-one-or-more-are/